# Fixing NGUniversal window is not defined error

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have an Angular 16.2.12 application that I just added `ng-universal` to.  When I run the `npm run dev:ssr` command I get an error saying the following.

> ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined

It comes from a line of code in my `app.component.ts` file where I reference the `window` object like this.

```
private ScrollWatcher : Observable<Event> = fromEvent(window, 'scroll');
```

Off top I know this is because the `window` object isn't available yet because the app is rendering on the server before being sent to the browser where the `window` object exist, but now I'm confused as to how I should address this problem.  Essentially I should somehow tell the app to wait until it reaches the browser before it tries to access the `window` element but I don't even know what I should be looking into to figure this out.  Does anybody know how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement any server-side dom implementation and integrate it into your server to make the `window` available on the server.

For example, you can use [domino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/domino) if your angular universal server is in express

```
const domino = require("domino");
const win = domino.createWindow(templateA);
global["document"] = win.document;
```

Add this code to your `server.ts` file and it should work.
Alternatively, if you do not intend to utilize the code on the server you can just use a platform check using platform ID and run it only on browser.